# Using a client certificate (host, crt, key, passphtase) in RestAssured

Tags: rest-assured, web-api-testing

Postman in the last update caused the removal of my collections also want to use REST ASSURED for API testing. I had a client certificate configured in postman

[postman client cert config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8EoH.png)

How do I configure this in code so that everything works?

i tried something like this but i could not find an answer...

`import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ApiTest {

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setup() {
    RestAssured.baseURI = "https://mywebsitewhichneedcrt.com";
}

@Test
public void testWithClientCertificate() {
    String certificatePath = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Web\\cert\\mycert.crt";
    String keyPath = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Web\\cert\\mycert.key";
    String passphrase = "000000";

    RestAssured
            .given()
            .relaxedHTTPSValidation()
            .keyStore(certificatePath, passphrase)
            .when()
            .post("/endpoint")
            .then()
            .statusCode(201);
}
```

}
`

Comment: And what is your problem? I don't see any error.

Comment: @lucas-nguyen-17 i receive javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Comment: could you add stack trace to the question?